# ActionView::Template::Errorが解決できません

Tags: ruby-on-rails

アプリケーションにて、モーダルウインドウ作成指定おります。実行するボタンを押したところ、ターミナルに下記の様なエラーが出ました

```html
ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial attendances/_edit-overtime_request, application/_edit-overtime_request with {:locale=>[:ja], :formats=>[:js, :html, :text, :css, :ics, :csv, :vcf, :vtt, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :svg, :mpeg, :mp3, :ogg, :m4a, :webm, :mp4, :otf, :ttf, :woff, :woff2, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip, :gzip], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/私のuser名/projects/a_app/app/views"
):
```

テンプレートが合っていないのだと思い、controller、パーシャルファイル、js.erbを確認しましたが、
どこが誤っているのか、発見できませんでした。

初歩的な内容だとは思いますが、エラーを解決する術を教えていただけないでしょうか。

＊ファイルのディレクトリ＊

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

＊attendances_controller＊

```html
def edit_overtime_request
    @attendance = Attendance.find(params[:id])
    @user = User.find(@attendance.user_id)
  end

  def update_overtime_request
  end
  
private

    # モーダルの情報
    def overtime_params
      params.require(:user).permit(attendances: [:overtime_finished_at, :tomorrow, :overtime_work,:indicater_check])
    end
  end
```

＊edit_overtime_request.js.erb＊

```html
$("#edit-overtime_request").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'edit-overtime_request') %>");
$("#edit-overtime_request").modal("show");
```

＊_edit_overtime_request.html.erb＊

```html
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-center">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
      <h1 class="modal-title">残業申請</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <%= form_with(model: @attendance, url: attendances_edit_overtime_request_user_path(@attendance), local: true, method: :patch) do |f| %>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed user-table">
          <thead>
            <th>日付</th>
            <th>曜日</th>
            <th>終了予定時間</th>
            <th>翌日</th>
            <th>業務処理内容</th>
            <th>指示者確認
              <div class="maru size_small black">       
                <div class="letter3">印
              </div> 
            </th>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <% css_class = 
            case $days_of_the_week[day.worked_on.wday]
              when '土'
                'text-primary'
              when '日'
                'text-danger'
              end
              %>
            <td><%= l(day.worked_on, format: :short) %></td>
            <td class="<%= css_class %>"><%= $days_of_the_week[day.worked_on.wday] %></td>
            <td><%= f. time_select :overtime_finished_at,{class: "form-control bootstrap-date-only-width"} %></td>
            <td><%= f.check_box :tomorrow,id: "tomorrow" %></td>
            <td><%= f.text_fild :overtime_work, class:"form-control" %></td>
            <td><%= f.select :indicater_check,{'なし':1, '申請中':2, '承認':3, '否認':4},{ class: 'form-control input-sm' , required: true } %></td>
          </tbody>
        </table>
            <%= f.submit "変更を送信する", class: "btn btn-primary btn-block" %>
      <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

＊routes.rb＊

```ruby
resources :users do
    collection { post :import }
    member do
      get 'edit_basic_info'
      patch 'update_basic_info'
      patch 'update_index'
      get 'attendances/edit_one_month'
      patch 'attendances/update_one_month'
    end
    collection do
      get 'working'
    end
    resources :attendances, only: [:update] do
        get 'edit_overtime_request'
        patch 'update_overtime_request'
    end 
  end
```

宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: ビューとコントローラだけでは再現や推測がむずかしいと思われるので、`routes.rb`の内容も記載していただければ回答しやすくなるとおもいます！

Comment: お答えいただき、ありがとうございます。routes.rbを記載させていただきますので、宜しくお願い致します

Answer (score 0):

`edit_overtime_request.js.erb`のrenderが、`render 'edit-overtime_request'`となっているため、要求するファイル名が合っていないようです。
`render 'edit_overtime_request'`（「edit」の後ろの「-」を「_」）にするか、ビューのファイル名を`_edit-overtime_request.html.erb`にすれば直ると思われます。